# how can I create custom keyboard for pin code input in react native without any libraries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I have created this code but it isn't working, I have created four input fields for pin code when users press the numeric it should move to the input field and turn that fields in the mask, like in * part so I am trying to add that one but something I am missing also I am not getting the four digits pin code when console the function please help me out.

```
import React, { Component, useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ImageBackground,
  SafeAreaView,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableOpacityBase,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";
import Theme from "../../utils/Theme";
import OTPInputView from "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input";
const hRem = AppStore.screenHeight / 812;
const wRem = AppStore.screenWidth / 375;

class PinAuthentication extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      passcode: ["", "", "", ""],
    };
  }

  onPressNumber = (num) => {
    const tempcode = this.state.passcode;
    for (let i = 0; i < tempcode.length; i++) {
      if (tempcode[i] == "") {
        tempcode[i] = num;
        break;
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }
    this.setState({ passcode: tempcode });
  };

  onPressCancel = (num) => {
    const tempcode = this.state.passcode;
    for (let i = tempcode.length; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (tempcode[i] != "") {
        tempcode[i] = "";
        break;
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }
    this.setState({ passcode: tempcode });
  };

  render() {
    let numbers = [
      { id: 1 },
      { id: 2 },
      { id: 3 },
      { id: 4 },
      { id: 5 },
      { id: 6 },
      { id: 7 },
      { id: 8 },
      { id: 9 },
      {
        id: 10,
      },
      { id: 0 },
      {
        id: 11,
      },
    ];
    return (
      <>
        <ImageBackground
          style={styles.container}
          source={require("../../assets/Images/SliderImages/Background02sc.png")}
        />
        <View style={styles.headerStyle}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image
              style={styles.backButton}
              source={require("../../assets/Images/SliderImages/Icon/BackButton.png")}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.pinText}>Set new PIN</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View></View>
        <View></View>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.pinConfirmationText}>Enter new PIN</Text>
        </View>
        {/* <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
        <OTPInputView
          style={{ width: "80%", height: 200 }}
          pinCount={4}
          // code={this.state.code} //You can supply this prop or not. The component will be used as a controlled / uncontrolled component respectively.
          // onCodeChanged = {code => { this.setState({code})}}
          autoFocusOnLoad
          codeInputFieldStyle={styles.underlineStyleBase}
          codeInputHighlightStyle={styles.underlineStyleHighLighted}
          onCodeFilled={(code) => {
            console.log(`Code is ${code}, you are good to go!`);
          }}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          // keyboardType={false}
        />
      </View> */}
        <View style={styles.codeContainer}>
          {this.state.passcode.map((x) => {
            let codes = x != "" ? styles.inputBox1 : styles.inputBox;
            return (
              <View style={codes}>{/* <Text style={codes}></Text> */}</View>
            );
          })}
        </View>

        <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
          <View style={styles.numberContainer}>
            {numbers.map((num, numb) => {
              return (
                <>
                  {num.id == 10 ? (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      key={num.id}
                      onPress={() => this.onPressCancel()}
                      style={styles.number}
                    >
                      <Image
                        style={styles.img}
                        source={require("../../assets/Images/SliderImages/Icon/icons_cancel_last_digit.png")}
                      />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  ) : num.id == 11 ? (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      key={num.id}
                      onPress={() => this.onPressCancel()}
                      style={styles.number}
                    >
                      <Image
                        style={styles.img}
                        source={require("../../assets/Images/SliderImages/Icon/icons_check.png")}
                      />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  ) : (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      key={num.id}
                      onPress={() => this.onPressNumber(num.id)}
                      style={styles.number}
                    >
                      <Text style={styles.numberText}>{num.id}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  )}
                </>
              );
            })}
          </View>
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default PinAuthentication;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: "#021831",
  },
  headerStyle: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: hRem * 56,
    marginHorizontal: wRem * 24,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  backButton: {
    width: wRem * 12,
    height: hRem * 21,
  },
  pinText: {
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginLeft: wRem * 101,
    fontSize: hRem * 18,
    ...Theme.encodeSansMed1,
    lineHeight: hRem * 16,
  },
  pinConfirmationText: {
    textAlign: "center",
    marginTop: hRem * 44,
    color: "white",
    ...Theme.encodeSansMed3,
    lineHeight: hRem * 19.07,
  },
  borderStyleBase: {
    width: 30,
    height: 45,
  },

  borderStyleHighLighted: {
    borderColor: "#707070",
  },

  underlineStyleBase: {
    width: wRem * 62,
    height: 45,
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },

  underlineStyleHighLighted: {
    borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
  },
  number: {
    width: wRem * 77,
    height: hRem * 77,
    borderRadius: wRem * 77,
    backgroundColor: "#000000",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginHorizontal: wRem * 12,
    marginVertical: hRem * 9,
  },
  numberContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    marginTop: hRem * 95,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    shadowColor: Theme.shadow_Button,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 1,
      height: 1,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 1.5,
    shadowRadius: 5,

    elevation: 3,
  },
  numberText: {
    ...Theme.encodeSansMed4,
    // lineHeight: hRem * 16,
    position: "absolute",
    textAlign: "center",
    color: Theme.white_color,
  },
  codeContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginHorizontal: wRem * 49,
    marginTop: hRem * 50,
  },
  code: {
    width: wRem * 62,
    height: hRem * 2,
    borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 13,
  },
  inputBox: {
    width: wRem * 62,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    // height: 13,
    // width: 13,
    borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
    // alignItems: "center",
    // justifyContent: "space-between",
    // backgroundColor: "white",
    // borderRadius: 13,
  },
  inputBox1: {
    width: wRem * 62,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    // height: 13,
    // width: 13,
    borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
    // alignItems: "center",
    // justifyContent: "space-between",
    // backgroundColor: "white",
    // borderRadius: 13,
  },
  inputText: {
    color: "white",
    ...Theme.encodeSansMed3,
    paddingBottom: hRem * 21,
    backgroundColor: "green",
    width: 20,
  },
  inputText1: {
    color: "white",
    ...Theme.encodeSansMed3,
    paddingBottom: hRem * 21,
  },
  img: {
    width: wRem * 30,
    height: hRem * 22,
  },
});
```

I have created this code but it isn't working, I have created four input fields for pin code when users press the numeric it should move to the input field and turn that fields in the mask, like in * part so I am trying to add that one but something I am missing also I am not getting the four digits pin code when console the function